# OSB - FTP files without specfing download directory

Tags: ftp, osb

Can't find online resources about this, so posting my question here. My set up I like this:

1) OSB resides on serverA
2) OSB must connect to serverB via FTP
    - get file
    - archive file (in a directory on serverB)
    - delete file (from original location on ServerB)
    - no download directory (file is uploaded and transformed in osb and loaded in db)

How this can be accomplished using OSB?

Answer (score 1):

I never did something alike, but I suggest to use a FTP adapter,  it will allow you to pull the file on server B using FTP and delete it after it has been retrieved successfully. You can use other FTP adapter (Operation Type: Put) to backup the retrieved file in other location.

Comment: Same can be achieved using ftp protocol when creating proxy service in OSB. Crucial is that I want only to load the file and I don't want to save it in another server.

Comment: @Alex oh yes, I see.  Have you explored the Post Read Actions for FTP transport?  According to the doc: This specifies whether the files should be deleted or archived after being read by the service. By default, the files are deleted after reading.